# Testing callback functions were called with Jasmine in an Angular project

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have a breadcrumbs component in my Angular project where you pass in a callback function that gets called when the breadcrumb is clicked.

The user passes in an object that contains the info to render a breadcrumb, along with a callback for when the breadcrumb is clicked.

The callback is added to the breadcrumb's `onclick` event and called when the user clicks on one.

```
<li *ngFor="let breadcrumb of breadcrumbs">
  <span (click)="breadcrumb.callback()">{{breadcrumb.title}}</span>
</li>
```

This is what I've tried:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [BreadcrumbsTestComponent, Breadcrumbs]
  });
}));

it('should call given callback when breadcrumb is clicked', async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BreadcrumbComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const breadcrumbElements = fixture.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.breadcrumb');

  breadcrumbElements.forEach(breadcrumb => {
    breadcrumb.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(breadcrumb.callback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
}));

const breadcrumbs = [
  {
    title: 'First Page',
    path: '/first',
    current: false,
    callback: jasmine.createSpy('callback')
  }, {
    title: 'Second Page',
    path: '/second',
    current: true,
    callback: jasmine.createSpy('callback')
  }
];

@Component({
  template: `<breadcrumbs [breadcrumbs]="breadcrumbs"></breadcrumbs>`
})
class BreadcrumbsTestComponent {
  breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
}
```

How do I test that the callback was called in my Jasmine testing?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried spyOn() in Jasmine?

Comment: You could inject your array of breadcrumbs as a value provider and then, in your unit test, register an artificial array of breadcrumbs with callbacks that set some flag you can test.  You could also make all the callbacks something like `this.navService.changeView` and then inject a fake navService.

Comment: @Esaith Yeah I've tried `createSpy`. Admittedly, I'm new to Jasmine so I'm still trying to wrap my head around it's espionage concepts.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm answering from what I've learnt, so it's probably not right, but it feels logical to me, so here it is !)

When you make unit testing, you're supposed to test if the code you wrote is working as expected. This is done to prevent side effects when you make a modification.

In your case, what you're doing is testing if the framework is doing its job (which is emitting an event).

I belive that's not what you should do : this kind of tests would be made for e2e testing, where you should test from one end (front-end) to another (back-end).

This means that if I were you, I would only test that the function `callback` of the breadcrumb does what it is expected to do.

Let's assume it makes the breadcrumb blink : if you test that the breadcrumb is blinking, you will make an useful test.
Because if one day, you decide that the breadcrumb should instead change color and not blink, your test will throw an error.
Meanwhile, if you want to test that the function is indeed called, the test will pass even if you drastically changed the logic of your callback.

That's what my *bottom line* is : **test what the callback does, not if it's called**.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You usage of create spy is correct. You can also omit the name in the create spy in this case. Did it not work in your test?

What you can change is to not create the test component and just test the breadcrumbs component directly. In this case I think you don't need a wrapper component it just complicates things. Then the test would look like this:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './breadcrumbs.component';
import { Breadcrumb } from '../breadcrumb/breadcrumb';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

describe('BreadcrumbsComponent', () => {
  let component: BreadcrumbsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BreadcrumbsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BreadcrumbsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BreadcrumbsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should call given callback when breadcrumb is clicked', async(() => {
    const breadcrumbs: Breadcrumb[] = [
      {
        title: 'First Page',
        path: '/first',
        current: false,
        callback: jasmine.createSpy()
      }, {
        title: 'Second Page',
        path: '/second',
        current: true,
        callback: jasmine.createSpy()
      }
    ];
    component.breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const breadcrumbElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('span'));

    breadcrumbElements.forEach(breadcrumb => {
      breadcrumb.nativeElement.click();
    });

    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      breadcrumbs.forEach(breadcrumb => {
        expect(breadcrumb.callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      });
    });
  }));
});
```

I used the code from the first box as the code for the breadcrumbs component that is why I then query for the span elements to click them in the test.